# How to update values in object in nested array with json server?

Tags: javascript, json, json-server

I have a problem which so far I am unable to solve. Well, I create an application to manage the tournament with NES games, I have there a module with a table that I would like to update after the team wins the match. I would like to add that I had to apply a structure composed of two arrays in the array because each of them is responsible for another of the tournament groups: green and red. I am using a json server. I can not reach my values in the attached structure. How should the request look like to update eg the number of points of the first team? What endpoint will allow you to update the data contained in these arrays? PATCH does not work, it returns 404. Thank you in advance for your help.

```
{"standings":[
  [{
     "id":"1", 
     "name":"Team1",
     "matches":0,
     "points":0,
     "gamesFor":0,
     "gamesAgainst":0
   }, {
     "id":"2", 
     "name":"Team2",
     "matches":0,
     "points":0,
     "gamesFor":0,
     "gamesAgainst":0
  }, {
     "id":"3", 
     "name":"Team3",
     "matches":0,
     "points":0,
     "gamesFor":0,
     "gamesAgainst":0
 }],[{
   "id":"1", 
   "name":"Team4",
   "matches":0,
   "points":0,
   "gamesFor":0,
   "gamesAgainst":0
 }, {
   "id":"2", 
   "name":"Team5",
   "matches":0,
   "points":0,
   "gamesFor":0,
   "gamesAgainst":0
 }, {
   "id":"3", 
   "name":"Team6",
   "matches":0,
   "points":0,
   "gamesFor":0,
   "gamesAgainst":0
 }] ]}
```

Comment: have you tried to establish a connection to the server? (btw, the question far to broad without any code.)

Comment: I think that this is a problem with the route, when I send updated data to the part of Json responsible for the results schedule, the data is updated without any problem. It has a different structure: an array with objects inside.